What does a family of curves, $\pi:X\to \triangle$ locally look like?
On Geometry of Algebraic Curves, vol 2, page 146 and 147 is writen:

In the last paragraph on page 147, they say:

We may then assume,.... that there is an open neighborhood $V$ of the node of the central fiber which is biholomorphic to
$$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb C^2:|x|<2,|y|<2\}$$

By definition of a node, there is a neighborhood W of the node, that us biholomorphic to $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb C^2:xy=0\}$. From this, how did they get that $V$?

and that $\pi$ is locally given by $xy=t$.

What do they mean with that?
I know that a node has a neighborhood that is locally isomorphic to $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb C:xy=0\}$, as $X_0$ is the nodal curves, for $t\in\triangle $, close to 0, $X_t=\pi^{-1}(t)$ is smooth, but I get stucked. I will really want to understand this, maybe is simple, but I do not get it. How do I write it formally? With explicti isomorphism, if there exists.
Thank you.
Attempt 1
If they say that $\pi$ is "locally", I understand that there is a Neighborhood $U_0\subset X$, of $X_0$, so that $\pi|_{U_0}:U_0\to \pi(U_0)$.
Let $M_0=\{m= ((x,y),t)\in \mathbb C^2\times U_0:xy=t\}$ and
$$\rho_0:M_0\to \pi(U_0),\quad\rho_0((x,y),t)=t,$$ then its fiber is
$$(M_0)_t:=\rho_0^{-1}(t)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb C^2:xy=t\}.$$
Consider the identity map $Id:\pi(U_0) \to \pi(U_0)$, then we take the pullback of $M_0$ by $Id$ and get the square diagram
\begin{array}{ccc}Id^*M_0 & \xrightarrow{} & M_0 \\ \downarrow{} & & \downarrow{\rho_0} \\ \pi(U_0) & \xrightarrow{Id} & \pi(U_0)\end{array}
$$Id^*M_0=\{(t,m)\in\triangle \times \pi(U_0)/i(t)=\rho(m)\}.$$
Hence, looking at fibers,$$(I ^*M)_{t}=M_{i(t)}=M_t$$
So, when they say that $\pi$ is locally $xy=t$, what they mean is that there is a neighborhood of $X_0$, $U_0\subset X$ and a family
$$\rho_0:M_0\to \pi(U_0)$$
such that:
$U_0=Id*(M_0)$?

As you write, you have local coordinates $x,y$ of $X$ at $p$, such that
$$X_0 = \{(x,y) : xy=0\}.$$
"Local coordinates" means that $x,y$ give an isomorphism of some neighbourhood $V \subset X$ to an open disc
$$V \xrightarrow{\cong} \Delta_{\varepsilon}^2 = \{(x,y) : |x|,|y|< \varepsilon\} \subset \mathbb C^2,$$
and under this isomorphism, $X_0$ gets mapped to the set
$$\{(x,y) : xy=0\} \subset \Delta_\varepsilon^2.$$
If you replace $x$ by $\frac 2 \varepsilon x$ and $y$ by $\frac 2 \varepsilon y$, you get an isomorphism
$$V \xrightarrow{\cong} \Delta_2^2 = \{|x|<2, |y|<2\}.$$


and that π is locally given by $xy=t$.

What do they mean with that?

I think this is quite sloppy from the authors. I guess they mean that under the isomorphism $V \to \Delta_2^2$, the fibration $\pi: X \to \Delta$ may be identified with the map
$$\Delta_2^2 \ni (x,y) \mapsto xy \in \Delta_4^1 \subset \mathbb C.$$
(Here I have to write $\Delta_4$ because that is where the map from $\Delta_2$ ends up in).
Why is that true? Think of $\pi$ as a function in $x,y$. By choice of the local coordinates,
$$\{(x,y):\pi(x,y)=0\} = X_0 = \{(x,y) : xy = 0\}.$$
By Rückert's Nullstellensatz, there exists a local function $u(x,y)$ with $u(0,0) = 1$, such that
$$\pi(x,y) = u(x,y)xy.$$
Replace $x$ by $u(x,y)\cdot x$ to obtain a new coordinate system, where $\pi(x,y) = xy$. This means exactly that the fiber of $\pi$ over $t \in \Delta$ is
$$\{(x,y) : xy = t\}.$$
Now you might have to do the rescaling thing from above again, because $u$ might not be defined on all of $\Delta_2^2$. It might be better to do those steps in different order.

Thank you very much, I will study what you wrote.
